# How to link to FORTRAN library via numpy distutils

Tags: python, numpy, fortran, f2py

I'm having trouble getting my setup.py script to work properly when linking to FORTRAN libraries.

I have almost no experience with libraries, so I may use the incorrect terminology. I have a fortran module which uses the FMLIB fortran package. The FMLIB package contains three f95 files which I have compiled to .o files. This module is in turn used by a python module. In the setup.py file, I use Extension:

```
shapelets = Extension('PyCosmology.shapelets.fort.shapelets', 
                     ['PyCosmology/shapelets/fort/find_coeffs.f90'],
                       libraries = [<DIRECTORY>./FM.o'
                       '<DIRECTORY>/FMSAVE.f95',
                       '<DIRECTORY>/FMZM90.f95'],
                       extra_f90_compile_args=['-Wtabs'],
                       f2py_options=['--quiet'])
```

However, when I try installing it says that it can't use FMZM because no .mod file can be found. Am I supposed to use a different keyword in Extension to link to the libraries, or link to the mod files instead? Or is there something else I should be doing? The documentation for distutils is relatively sparse.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out.

Just need to add `include_dirs = ['<DIRECTORY WITH .MOD FILES>']` and `library_dirs = [<DIRECTORY>]` and then change the libraries keyword to contain only filenames with no path.

Seems to work.